# Adding A View To An Existing View Programatically

Tags: objective-c, macos

How can you add or replace a view within a view with code?  I'm programming for OSX, not IOS.

I am using a drawer that utilizes a custom view.  In the custom view I have two boxes, one with a custom set of icons that I want to stay static and another box that has the information related to that button.  What I want to do is when a user clicks one of the buttons that the 2nd box view changes to reflect the info for that button.

For example, I have five buttons and the default 2nd box is "Info", if the user clicks the 2nd button in the first box view I want to change the 2nd box to be the "List" box instead while the 1st box with the buttons stays intact.

I'm not sure how this would impact constraints since while the first box is a fixed size, the 2nd box needs to be dynamic so that it fills in the "rest of the space" so that when the drawer size changes with the window size that the 2nd box is taking up the remaining real estate.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the number of buttons in advance?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented such a scenario in the past using a tabless `NSTabView`, and an `NSSegmentedControl` (for the buttons). The `NSTabView` has it's `-takeSelectedTabViewItemFromSender:` action connected to the `NSSegmentedControl`, using Interface Builder.

In the Connections Inspector, this shows up like so:

[image]

This has the effect that the index of the selected `NSTabViewItem` in your `NSTabView` will correspond to the index of the selected segment in the `NSSegmentedControl`.